# Drupal module url handling

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have module that shows specific content based on url. Now it looks like this:

{mysitename}/country/{slug}

In hook menu:

```
  $items['country'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_catalog_content_output',
    'page arguments' => array(0), 
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
```

But now, in seo purposes, I need url like this:

{mysitename}/{slug}

How this can be done?

And one more following question: how to make exception for some specific urls like {my sitename}/blog, i.e. if no object with current slug is found module should redirect handling to drupal core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to create a menu item which applies to domain.com/*
Try to approach the problem from the other way around. Create a module which matches the current url (domain.com/foo) against a list of urls (foo, bar) and (301) redirects to the correct page if match found. I hope this makes sense.

Some functions to get you started:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7